# How can one use a local pipelined function returning a local type in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, pipelined-function

After creation of a local pipelined PL/SQL function returning locally defined type I found no way to use it. Is there one? By being local I mean the function and the type is visible only within some other PL/SQL block and therefore cannot be used in SQL:

```sql
declare
    type foo_rec is record (
        foo_id number,
        foo_date date
    );

    type foo_tbl is table of foo_rec;

    function get_some_foo
      return foo_tbl pipelined
    is
      out_rec foo_rec;
    begin
      for cur in (
        select 1 foo_id, sysdate foo_date from dual
        union all
        select 2 foo_id, sysdate+1 foo_date from dual
      )
      loop
        out_rec.foo_date := cur.foo_date;
        out_rec.foo_id := cur.foo_id;
        pipe row(out_rec);
      end loop;
    end get_some_foo;
begin
    null; -- how to use get_some_foo() here?
end;
/
```

Comment: I don't believe you can, no.  A pipelined table function really only makes sense in the context of a SQL statement so creating one that can't be used in SQL doesn't make much sense.  If you want a local function that operates on a collection, it would make much more sense to define a function that returns a collection rather than creating a pipelined table function.

Comment: Two things:  1)  Why does the function need to be locally defined?  2)  If it does need to be locally defined, can you just simply declare the cursor you want to use in the declare section and use it locally wherever you like?